# Update/Insert CurrencyType record using apex Anonymous Window

Tags: currencytype

Hi Experts the below code returns 400 error code when i try to insert record for currencytype.
Please give the solutions

```java
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://aravinthdev-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/CurrencyType/');
req.setBody('{"Name": "IDR", "USD": "1.1152", "isactive"="true", "DecimalPlaces": "2" }');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+ UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issue with the body of your request: there is no field "Name" and `"isactive"="true"` makes it an invalid JSON.

In the [CurrencyType documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_currencytype.htm) you can find the needed fields.
I would like to draw attention on these two fields:

- `IsoCode`: three-letter currency ISO codes defined by the ISO 4217 standard
- `ConversionRate`: Conversion rate of this currency type **against the corporate currency**.

If your corporate currency is "IDR" and you want to set the conversion rate of "USD" the body string should be:
`'{"IsoCode": "USD", "ConversionRate": 1.1152, "IsActive": true, "DecimalPlaces": 2 }'`

So the whole code block should be:

```java
String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
String endpoint = '/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/CurrencyType/';
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(baseUrl+endpoint);
req.setBody('{"IsoCode": "USD", "ConversionRate": 1.1152, "IsActive": true, "DecimalPlaces": 2 }');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+ UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now